# I want to create a series of sub sheets by Primary Program (a column header) that will update when the Master Data Set (original sheet) is edited

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm fairly tech savvy for someone not anywhere near the industry, and I generally can pick up new information and skills. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction for the request below.

**Project**
I am tracking a large amount of volunteer data by program.

**Request**
I would like to be able to filter data by program, but into individual tabs/sheets within the Google Sheets document, that will update as the Main Tab/Sheet is edited throughout the year. It needs to be functional in Google Sheets. It also needs to be able to import new data to the correct location (sorted by Primary Program column) as new information is added to the Master Sheet.

**Reason**
This will allow for individual program teams to more easily look through their own program data without having to filter and sort. They could try using filters of course, but I work in an industry where tech literacy greatly varies and I cannot have someone accidentally mucking up a spreadsheet trying to filter. And then there are several teams with individuals who are not looking to learn how to filter when we offer to teach them.

**Note**
I tried individually moving data over by hand, and then realized I'd have to remember to edit individual tabs for each edit made on the Main Sheet, and I thought to myself 'there's definitely a better way for this that someone else already figured out.' So here I am! I also tried googling and watched a few videos on using Macros but that seemed more complicated than I'm expecting. I've dabbled in VLOOKUP before and am trying to remember if that would serve this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The `FILTER()` function should give you exactly what you’re looking for.

In each tab you can add a `FILTER()` function, point it at the master sheet, and set it to only pull the data you want based on the primary column you’re interested in.

**PRO TIP:** When you specify the range to be filtered leave the last number empty to that as new data gets added the filter function looks for it. **For example**—if your data is in Sheet1 columns A through G, set the range you want to filter as `Sheet1!A1:G`. That way, even if your data currently only goes to row 100, when you add data alter it will be captured. If you set it as `Sheet1!A1:G100` then as you add data to Sheet1 going beyond the 100th row you’d have to update all your filter queries and that will not be fun :)

Comment: Yes, this, thank you! I knew it had to be easier than I was making it haha. And thank you for the Pro Tip! That was one of the questions I had when I was thinking it through - how to leave it opened ended for new data.

Comment: Glad I could help @AllisonSears! Mind marking the question as answered if that resolved your issues. We get points for correct answers, it’s just like school :)